# Combine git add . and git commit

Tags: git

How to combine two git command. In particular, I want to combine *git add .* and *git commit -m "message"*. For example,

```
gaddmit "message"
```

should be equivalent to:

```
git add .

git commit -m "message"
```

where *gaddmit* is the alias I want to use.

Comment: You can write shell script to achieve this. BTW I didnt vote down, bcoz usually first comment is by the person who voted down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make an alias (put this line into your `.bashrc`):

```
alias gaddmit='git add . && git commit -m'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create an alias in your .gitconfig, something like this perhaps:

```
[alias]
    addmit = !git add . && git commit -m
```

Then just do:

```
git addmit "my commit message"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**

Create a function in your `.bashrc` file and add an alias

```
add_and_commit() {
  git add .
  git commit -m "$1"
}
alias gaddmit=add_and_commit
```

Now you should be able to call `gaddmit "message"`

Answer (score 2):

```
git commit -a -m "message"
```

will work similarly to what you want. The difference is that this will not stage files that you have never previously added to git.

If you really need an alias, you can use the suggestions in the other answers.

---

Note: I recommend adding files individually instead of doing it all at once with `git add .` or `git commit -a`. Adding files individually (I'd recommend using the cool patch (`-p`) option) lets you review and make sure that changes should actually be added to the commit